# Can I restrict openssh to only allow public keys with pass phrases

Tags: linux, ssh

Is it possible to configure ssh using `PubkeyAuthentication yes` but only allowing pub/private key pairs with a passphrases?

Comment: See this similar/related question: http://serverfault.com/q/82649/253490

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't find that question earlier when I searched sf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the server has no knowledge of the protection used for the SSH key on the client.

It could be a passworded PEM file, a key loaded into an agent, stored on a smartcard, etc -- all the server knows is the client responded with the correctly signed response.